# PHP - Variable, only text allowed

Tags: php, html, string, function

I am making a website (dah), and I need to have a function.

That function would make the string in only text.

Like:

```
$string = "Hello world<div width="100000">aaa</div>";
```

In html, that would get very bad. I am trying to use a function to make this in text, like:

```
$string = function($string);
```

And that would only return solid text!

Comment: I don't understand what you need

Comment: You could start with `strip_tags`...

Comment: So, you want to strip any HTML tags within a specified string?

Comment: strip_tags(), preg_replace(), others

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags), which will remove the harmful tags from the input:

```
$string = strip_tags( 'Hello world<div width="100000">aaa</div>');
echo $string; // Output: Hello worldaaa
```

Comment: congratulations on understanding what this question was about :)

Comment: Provided it was really about that. I still can't tell.

Comment: @JohnLemon be real careful strip_tags() will not work on badly formed html. **Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.**

Comment: untill some one posts a comment with broken html that is.